# How to send text with photo from Telegramm bot

Tags: python, image, text, telegram-bot, sendmessage

I need the bot to send a message when the inline button is pressed, which contains a link to the photo and text.
Moreover, in the message I need to display the title, after the photo, and at the end of the message - the text. But as a result now, the text is displayed in the message, and the photo is at the end of the message.
What do I need to do to get the photo at the beginning of the post?
When sending, I use the send_message method and parse mode "HTML".

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda callback_query: True)
async def some_callback_handler(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    if callback_query['data'] == 'info':
              text = '''One night, an armed man and woman break into his house, and his son, Blake, 
                        tackles one of them. Hutch is reluctant to intervene and allows the thieves to 
                        leave. The incident causes everyone to think he is a failure. Hutch contacts his 
                        half-brother Harry on a hidden radio in his office and explains that he held back 
                        because the burglars were desperate, scared, and using an unloaded gun.'''
              img_link = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c7/Nobody_2021_Film_Poster.jpeg'
              text = '<a href="' + img_link + '">poster</a>\n' + text
              await bot.send_message(chat_id=callback_query.message.chat.id, text=text)
```

I cannot use the send_photo method with the text in the caption field, since the text field will be longer than 1024 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Only you have that sendPhoto method, Other option is send photo and message separately at the same time.